# Why didn't my pokemon's nickname come up in a battle at the battle spot

Tags: pokemon-sun-moon

When I was in a battle at the battle spot where u go after going in festival plaza then tap battle then tap free battle and then tap speacial pokemon not allowed option then choose team I battled and I sent out my shiny granbull that I nicknamed red jasper (I am not colorblind I named him that becouse I wanted to :)) but when I sent him out the name came up as granbull instead :/ is there's a reason why his nickname isn't shown in battles

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes names are 'reset to default' in online matches due to them containing bad words.

In the case of 'red jasper', it's apparently a term meaning 'erection', so that's why it must have gotten blocked.